# Opencart dissable missing orders

Tags: opencart

I implemented with my store,A invoice sistem.When is a missing order in my site , opencart creates a order ID, and in my invoice system the numbers of the invoice id is 53 and the next one is 65 because of the missing orders are getting an order id.How can i stop this?

Comment: Invoice numbers are separate to order ID and shouldn't have any gaps in the numbers. Order ID's need to have the missing order id capability for payments to work

Answer (score 2):

Its right process, when you come to the step five (Payment one) on checkout then OpenCart generate the order in database with status of Zero (0) because when user make payment then order_id will be goes to payment gateway website to maintain the payment. Once payment will be successfully then on the success controller OC update your order status Zero to in-progress & destroy the session variables for Shipping & payment etc.

So if any user come to checkout & goes to confirm section but didn't make the payment in that case order id will be generated in db, so there are no missing orders in your store, Don't worry about that.

I hope this will clear order id picture for you.

Comment: I have orders without any field completed just the order id ,IP, and cart contents.... , if i add to cart and go to checkourt after that exit, opencart registers an missing order with an id ..